# Add directory to rewriten URL without causing endless loop

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I desire to rewrite `public/xxx.html` to `/public/test/xxx.html`.  But using 
following results in an INTERNAL REDIRECT which causes it to occur again, and so on and so on.

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.+\.html)$ /public/test/$1 [NC,L]`
```

How can I change the URL directory without causing an endless loop?

```
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/xxx.html -> public/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3738f978/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/xxx.html -> public/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3738f978/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3738f978/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3738f978/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3738f978/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3737d938/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3737d938/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3737d938/initial/redir#2] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3737d938/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3737d938/initial/redir#2] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3737d938/initial/redir#2] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37397f48/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37397f48/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37397f48/initial/redir#3] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37397f48/initial/redir#3] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37397f48/initial/redir#3] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37397f48/initial/redir#3] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3739c678/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3739c678/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3739c678/initial/redir#4] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3739c678/initial/redir#4] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3739c678/initial/redir#4] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f3739c678/initial/redir#4] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a1088/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a1088/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a1088/initial/redir#5] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a1088/initial/redir#5] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a1088/initial/redir#5] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a1088/initial/redir#5] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a5af8/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a5af8/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a5af8/initial/redir#6] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a5af8/initial/redir#6] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a5af8/initial/redir#6] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373a5af8/initial/redir#6] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373aa830/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373aa830/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373aa830/initial/redir#7] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373aa830/initial/redir#7] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373aa830/initial/redir#7] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373aa830/initial/redir#7] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373af778/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373af778/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373af778/initial/redir#8] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373af778/initial/redir#8] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373af778/initial/redir#8] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373af778/initial/redir#8] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373b4be8/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373b4be8/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373b4be8/initial/redir#9] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373b4be8/initial/redir#9] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373b4be8/initial/redir#9] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373b4be8/initial/redir#9] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373ba1d8/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] add path info postfix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test -> /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373ba1d8/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html -> public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373ba1d8/initial/redir#10] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373ba1d8/initial/redir#10] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] rewrite 'public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html' -> '/public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373ba1d8/initial/redir#10] (2) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/mysite/html_sites/ with /
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f373ba1d8/initial/redir#10] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] internal redirect with /public/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/xxx.html [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mysite/html_sites/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] applying pattern '^public/(.+\\.html)$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
[test.sites.example.com/sid#7f8f37058e28][rid#7f8f37378b38/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/mysite/html_sites/] pass through /var/www/mysite/html_sites/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is indeed an infinite loop because your pattern is matching rewritten URI as well.

To fix you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^public/([^/.]+\.html)$ /public/test/$1 [NC,L]
```

`[^/.]+` will match any filename part just below `public/` but not below `public/test/`

Comment: Thanks anubhava,  Could you explain in detail what `[^/.]+` does?  Thanks

Comment: Never mind.  Match any set which doesn't contain `.`.